# Incorrect calling of external mp3 file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am getting Error:#2044, so I assumed that my code is wrong in calling the Sound functions but I can't seem to find where I am making the error.

```
        package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Tile extends MovieClip{

        public function GetAndSwitchKey():String {
            //Some Code//
            //Create sounds
            //------------> Start here
            var bSound:Sound = new Sound();
            var bReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("B.mp3");

            var oSound:Sound = new Sound();
            var oReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("O.mp3");

            var mSound:Sound = new Sound();
            var mReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("M.mp3");

            //Load sounds
            bSound.load(bReq);
            oSound.load(oReq);
            mSound.load(mReq);
            //<-------- End here
            //Some code//

            switch (temp) {
                case "B": bSound.play(); break;
                case "O": oSound.play(); break;
                case "M": mSound.play(); break;
            }
            //Some code//
        }
    }
}
```

The way I added the files is by placing them inside the same file as the Action script 3 file. I also then changed them in the propperties to be exportable for action script. But as far as I am aware I don't have to specify the directory since a copy is made in the SWF.

Comment: Try putting the mp3 files into the same folder where the swf gets published in.

Comment: I'll give it a try now

Comment: @DodgerThud where do you find the SWF file?

Answer (score -1):

Replacing the code indicated between the "start here" and "end here". This will resolve the error. And will call the sound file properly.

```
var mySoundHolder = new mySound();
```

Comment: This answer contains parts that are not located in the question. There is also no context. This answer will not help anyone else based on the question.

Comment: he asked a wrong question and give a wrong answer to that same question. He was trying to load external sound while his setup was made to play embedded sounds. There's nothing to learn from that except don't mix apple and oranges?

Comment: How is it not resolving the problem? The aim was to call a sound file and this resolves the problem. Don't get the error any more and the sound is called propperly. And @BotMaster, then post a answer yourself explaining what was wrong and to help other people.